# How to create a Chat callout in delphi

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I would like to create a chat ballon just like messengers does via FireMonkey TCalloutPanel , so how could I do that by giving it a text as a parameter then get the callout resized according to the text given ^^

Thanks in advance

Comment: will a tlistbox with custom styled tlistboxitems work for you app, or are you wanting like a component? a custom style of a tcalloutpanel and a ttext, could be used, then you could access the ttext with stylesdata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote this up quickly. Can use this as an example to work from to meet your specific needs/wants. Also, I would highly suggest going to the custom styling route as this way, adding TControls to the TListBoxItem ( although works ) makes the TListbox scrolling horrible.

```
procedure TForm1.LoadMessage(SelfSent:Boolean;msg:String;var LItem:TListBoxItem);
var
  panel:Tcalloutpanel;
  memo:TMemo;
begin
  panel:=TCalloutPanel.Create(LItem);
  panel.Parent:=LItem;
  panel.Align:=TAlignLayout.Client;
  panel.Margins.Left:=5;
  panel.Margins.Right:=5;
  panel.Margins.Top:=5;
  panel.Margins.Bottom:=5;
  if selfSent=true then
    panel.CalloutPosition:=TCalloutPosition.right
  else
    panel.CalloutPosition:=TCalloutPosition.Left;
  panel.CalloutOffset:=10;
  memo:=TMemo.Create(panel);
  memo.Parent:=panel;
  memo.Align:=TAlignLayout.Contents;
  memo.Margins.Left:=15;
  memo.Margins.Right:=15;
  memo.Margins.Top:=5;
  memo.Margins.Bottom:=5;
  memo.HitTest:=false;
  memo.Text:=msg;

  LItem.Height:=memo.ContentBounds.Height+30;
  if LItem.Height<60 then
    LItem.Height:=70;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks mate , tah's really helped kudos 2 ya ^^